# Microsoft Office Interop: Detemine empty columns in excel

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am using Micosoft Interop to read excel file. If the data is as mentioned in the screen below:

[image: Excel Data]

When I read this data and display it in data grid, it displays and empty column. Is there any way to determine empty column in excel interop??? Please guide me. Do let me know if you need any other information.

Regards,
Priyank

Comment: do let me know if you are not able to see the screenshot. I think there some problem with image upload or browser settings :( :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
public bool CheckIfEmptyCell(xlsSheet, row, column) {
    var cell = (Excel.Range)xlsSheet.Cells[row, column]);
    return (cell.Value2 == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value2.ToString())
}

....

var isEmpty = CheckIfEmptyCell(xlsSheet, 5, "D"); // D5 is empty?
```